# Java - Strings and the substring method

Tags: java, string, object, substring, allocation

I have some question that I wonder about. I know that string are immutable in Java and therefore a new string object is created rather than changed when for example assigning to a existing string object.

Now to my question. Let's suppose that I have the following piece of code:

```
String a = "Hello World";
String b = "Hello World";

String res = a.substring(0,4) + b.substring(6,10);
```

How many string objects will be created by the code at line 3 ? Will each call to substring create a new string object ? Will my code above generate 3 new string objects ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Strings in Java are immutable**. Basically this means that, once you create a string object, you won't be able to modify/change the content of a string. As a result, if you perform any manipulation on a string object which "appears to" change the content of the string, Java creates a new string object, and performs the manipulation on the newly created one.

Based on this, your code above appears to create five string objects - two are created by the declaration, two are created by calls to `substring`, and the last one is created after you concatenate the two pieces.

Immutability however leads to another interesting consequence. JVM internally maintains something like a string pool for creating string literals. For saving up memory, JVM will try to use string objects from this pool. Whenever you create a new string literal, JVM will loop into the pool to see if any existing strings can be used. If there is, JVM will simply use it and return it.

So, technically, before Java 7, JVM will create only one string object for your whole code. Even your `substring` calls won't create new string objects in the pool, it will use the existing "Hello World" one, but in this case it will only use characters from position 0 to 3 for your first call to substring, for example. Starting from Java 7, substring will not share the characters, but will create a new one. So, total object count will be 4 - the last one will be created with the concatenation of the two substrings.

**Edit**
To answer your question in the comment, take a look at [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.9) -

> In the Java programming language, unlike C, an array of char is not a
>   String, and neither a String nor an array of char is terminated by
>   '\u0000' (the NUL character).
>
> A String object is immutable, that is, its contents never change,
>   while an array of char has mutable elements.
>
> The method toCharArray in class String returns an array of characters
>   containing the same character sequence as a String. The class
>   StringBuffer implements useful methods on mutable arrays of
>   characters.

So, no, char arrays are not immutable in Java, they are mutable.

Comment: Technically, only 4 are created.  String literals in code are resolved with `String.intern()`, so a and b both refer to the exact same String at runtime.

Comment: "two are created by the declaration"?

Comment: Just one question, is char arrays mutable in java ?

Comment: Recent implementations of `String` in Java 7 no longer share the character array when `substring()` is called: it will create a new character array to back the substring.

Comment: `a.substring(0,4)` will return new String object `"Hell"`, `b.substring(6,10)` will return `"Worl"` object. When you concatenate them you will get another String object `"HellWorl"`. You also have `"Hello World"` in String pool so I don't get why `total object count will be 3`.

Comment: @Pshemo: Yup, you are right, I was thinking in terms of compile time constants (as both are string literals) but missed the point that method calls on strings do not evaluate to constant time expressions. Updated the answer.

Comment: As of jdk7 this answer is basically incorrect and should be heavily revised.

Comment: Is it true that the statement- 
String s=new String("hello world"); 
creates total two objects, one in Heap and another in Pool part?

Answer (score 0):

Literal a is created newly and kept in the pool.Literal b refer the a, it will not create new one instead.

The line 3 will create 3 new String since substring creates a new string and concatenate creates new Strings every time.

[String substring(int beginIndex,int endIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring
>   begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at
>   index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is
>   endIndex-beginIndex.

Comment: Care to explain why 2 and not 3 as said by Zim-Zam?

Comment: @AchintyaJha There are 2 `substring` calls + 1 concatenation.

Comment: That edit doesn't change the fact that it should be 3, while this answer said 2.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei I said 2 new with substring and  1 with concatenation.

Comment: Quote: The line 3 will create 2 new String